# Image is blocking my subheader I have on the A master pgs (needs to be on every page)

Tags: adobe-indesign, master-page

I have an image that I need at the top of the article but I also have the company name on every single page (it's an requirement) so I had the company name as a A master page and applied to every single page I have, but now this image is blocking the company name. I'm not sure how I fix this? Do I have to just write it out again manually in an ordinary text box?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

- Create a new layer.
- Place it at the top.
- Move the company name to this layer (but just keep it on the master page).
- This way it will always be on top on all pages.

Answer (score 1):

Remember - you can use layers in InDesing Master pages too, along with text wraps, etc. to keep things from overlapping actual page elements. If you want master elements to be above others; Simply create a new layer and move those Master Page elements (logos - navigation - graphics, etc.) to that layer in the layers palette. Lock that layer and be sure once you return back to your page from within the Master Page, you choose a layer to work on that is below your static Master elements.

Comment: Unfortunately, items that are on a master page will not be shown in the layers panel for the document page.  The only way that I know to make them show up is to override the master page items on the document page, and then you can see them, and change their order in the layers panel.

Comment: Excellent point—I completely failed to think about this. +1. @magerber Is it really important that it show up in the layers panel on the document page? None of the other headers would…

Comment: Only if you want to move it above items on the same layer.  

But, after reading the other answers here, I realized that I had forgotten that you could place the entire master page layer above the working layer on your document page.  I have a template that I use frequently that I specifically created the master page layer below the document layer because of a different issue specific to that document, and I was thinking about that particular document when I wrote my answer.  Oops!

Answer (score 0):

*Edited to correct myself:*

No, you don’t—you can keep it on the master page. See Galen Shaffer’s and Wolff’s replies for details.

---

*Original answer left here for posterity, giving an alternative approach that may perhaps be a better option in some limited circumstances:*

Elements that are on a master page will always, by definition, be behind any elements defined (or overridden) on individual document pages. That's their very nature.

You don't mention exactly what type of document you're working on, or whether you have facing pages and the page with the image may switch from a left page to a right page.

If text reflow may cause the page to change from a left to a right page, then start with step 1 below; otherwise start with step 2.

1. Make sure that your company name on the master page is set up in a way so that it automatically positions itself correctly regardless of whether it appears on a right or left page. If the name is centred, this is not a problem—just make sure the text frame spans from the left margin to the right margin and center the text. If it is justified towards or away from the spine, make sure to use these options in the justification settings, rather than just left- or right-aligning them individually.
2. Copy the text frame with the company name, paste-in-place it (Cmd/Ctrl + Alt + Shift + V) on the page with the image (in front of it), and then anchor it to somewhere relevant in the text on the page so it's an anchored object.
3. Hide the image so you can see the company name behind it (to check that the added one is positioned correctly).
4. In the frame’s anchored object properties, specify where to place the object on the page. If you have facing pages, make sure the vertical offset is based on the page *edge* and the horizontal offset on the page *margin*; if you don't, both can be based on either, just as long as it gets the object into the right position, exactly on top of the one on the master page.
5. Unhide the image.

This should give you a duplicate company name in the exact same location as the one on the master page. If you're using facing spreads, it should also make sure that if the text reflows, this company name that sits on top of the image on the page will move with it and be placed correctly on the page, regardless of whether it ends up being a left page or a right page.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is simply to use the Override Master Page option for that particular page.  You do that by clicking on the item while holding Ctrl+Shift/Cmd+Shift.

The way I would do this, in your situation, is to open up the layers panel, and find the image.  Either hide or lock it.  Then on the page itself, hold down Ctrl/Cmd+Shift and select the text frame with the company name (if you can't see the text box, you can use Ctrl/Cmd+Shift as you are drawing a bounding box over the approximate location of the text fame). Once you have selected the text frame, then use Object/Arrange to "Bring to Front."  Now go back into your layers panel and unfreeze or unhide your image.

I would only do this after you are sure that you will not be changing the pagination of your document.  Once you have overridden a master page item, it will no longer update if you make a change to the master pages, or if text flow makes your image move to a different page.

**ETA:**  *I am also leaving my answer here in case someone needs to know how to override a master page item. But I agree that it is not the best answer to the original question.*

Comment: The final paragraph is precisely why I did not suggest overriding the master page item, but adding one to the document page. Any text reflow will require re-applying the master page to and deleting the overridden object from the page where the image was originally, as well as re-overriding the header from the page where it ends up being.

Comment: I agree 100%, but as anyone who uses InDesign regularly knows, there are about 7,000 different ways to accomplish almost anything you might want to accomplish, so I thought it was worthwhile to throw out another option in case it was a situation where the image was not likely to move.